# Слитно или раздельно: "(не)отягощенного заботами"

Tags: орфография

Как пишется сочетание "чувства (не)отягощенного заботами полета"? Слитно или раздельно? В пособии - слитно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несомненно, НЕ нужно писать отдельно, так как у причастия "отягощённого" есть зависимое слово ЗАБОТАМИ.   
Это  Ю.Бондарев,  "Берег": 
..услышанной чужой речи, среди благостного салонного рая, ритуально освященного ласковыми улыбками длинноногих стюардесс, этих непорочных ангелов-хранителей душевного покоя в небе, - **чувство** не отягощенного заботами полета**** было знакомо Никитину...
[lib.ru](http://lib.ru)›Проза›BONDAREW/[shore.txt](http://shore.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Надо бы видеть все предложение, так как странно звучит фраза "чувства... полета" (слово "чувства", видимо, в род.пад.?). Если же смотреть на фразу в предложенном виде, то здесь классический пример причастия, которое пишется раздельно с частицей НЕ, так как имеется пояснительное слово

Comment: Виктор, спасибо,но никакого дополнительного контекста не прилагается.
Мне тоже показалось, что здесь необходимо писать раздельно.